# How to display Degree Celsius in a string in C++

Tags: c++, console

I need to display a string with values like 36 Deg Celsius.

```
string sFinish = NULL;
string sValue = "36"; 
sFinish.append(sValue);
sFinish.append(" Deg Celsuis");
cout<<"Degree = "<<sFinish;
```

I am not able to figure out how to display degree (o symbol) instead of writing "Deg Celsius".

If you just copy paste "°" string into code - it shows extra character - like this "Â°".

Comment: If there is no degree symbol on your keyboard, here is one `°` you can copy-paste in your code.

Comment: Use charmap, or alt+0176 (in the numpad), or copy this: °

Comment: @YodanTauber : Is their a way we can display it with copy pasting? :)

Comment: Yes, e.g. `sFinish.append("°C");`

Comment: No no.... u didnt get my question :) I mean any other alternative? converting ascii value of degree and then storing it....

Comment: @YodanTauber: It appears like 36 A with ~ on top of A.

Comment: Does it appear like that in your source code or in your output (e.g. console)? Have you tried saving your source as UTF-8?

Comment: It appears like this in output. saving source as in?

Comment: Why was this closed? This is [a nontrivial question](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Try:

```
std::cout << "Temperature: " << sValue << "\370";
```

Comment: +1, but `'\370'` To show that it's all only one character would probably be better.

Comment: Thanks... this works :) I also tried "\u2103" and this can be an alternate option :)

Answer (score 5):

You might find the following link helpful for the [full ascii table](http://www.ascii-code.com/).

Here is a solution I found here on SO: [Including decimal equivalent of a char in a character array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18184147/including-decimal-equivalent-of-a-char-in-a-character-array)

But to summarize, this would do fine

```
char * val = "37";
string temp(val);
temp.append("\xB0");    
cout << temp;
```

Comment: I found that \370 have the wrong character but \0xB0 gave the correct one.

Answer (score 3):

Just in-case if anyone wants to try this:

```
sFinish.append("\u2103");
```

this will display Deg celsius :)